# Changing user's wallpaper via system crontab

Tags: cron, awesome, wallpaper

I tried to set up wallpaper change via cron in `/etc/crontab`, but I failed.

DISPLAY env set directly / before cmd, but still it's not working:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0
* * * * * ad   env DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/bin/awsetbg -a -r /home/ad/img/beauty/
* * * * * ad   DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/bin/awsetbg -a -r /home/ad/img/beauty/
* * * * * ad   export DISPLAY=:0.0; /usr/bin/awsetbg -a -r /home/ad/img/beauty/
```

`su - user -c "cmd"` worked:

```
* * * * * root su - ad -c "DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/bin/awsetbg -a -r /home/ad/img/beauty/"
```

Now I'm using user's crontab (`crontab -e`) which works fine:

```
*/10 * * * * DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/bin/awsetbg -a -r /home/ad/img/beauty/
```

What else do I have to set?

cron's `env`:

```
MAILTO=root
SHELL=/bin/bash
USER=ad
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
PWD=/
SHLVL=1
HOME=/
LOGNAME=ad
DISPLAY=:0.0   # same result for DISPLAY=:0
_=/bin/env
```

Using `vixie-cron 4.1-r1` on Gentoo.

Comment: Solved during writing, so I'm leaving this puzzle to others. Rep for free!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's changing `HOME=/` to `HOME=/home/ad`.

Comment: Yes! I will explain in separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I totally forgot that `awsetbg` is just shell script which uses `$HOME` variable.

> ```
>   awsetbg - awesome wrapper tool to set background
> ```

So `HOME` needs to be set.

```
* * * * * ad   DISPLAY=:0,HOME=/home/ad /usr/bin/awsetbg -a -r /home/ad/img/beauty/
```

If you will use directly some app, it will work just with DISPLAY env:

```
* * * * * ad   DISPLAY=:0 feh --bg-max --randomize /home/ad/img/beauty/
```