# Why can I not run KDE redshift in a cronjob?

Tags: terminal, cron, kde

I'm running KDE Neon 5.14 (based on Ubuntu 18.04) and KDE Plasma 5.14.2.

A command `redshift` (`/usr/bin/redshift`) is provided to adapt the screen colors to red tones for evening/night. I can successfully run it on a terminal emulator, but not in a cronjob. This line from the user's crontab

```
15 19 * * * /usr/bin/redshift
```

has no effect.

What could be the reason? And how to correctly run `redshift` also as a cronjob?

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171744/changing-users-wallpaper-via-system-crontab

Comment: @JeffSchaller It works with `DISPLAY:=0.0`. Thank you!

Comment: Even if [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193827/what-is-display-0) and also [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171744/changing-users-wallpaper-via-system-crontab) are *related* to this problem, neither of them directly provides the answer needed here, which is: `DISPLAY:=0.0` must be set in the `env` of the cronjob.